# Is Axios is stable?

Tags: axios

I am finding that axios follows version like 0.19.x , 0.18.x
So I am confusion whether it is stable or there is some-kind of other pattern in version convention, so it starts with 0.x.x

Thanks!

Comment: Read about [Semver](https://semver.org). Check out [this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2265) as well.

Comment: still it does not clears whether axios is stable or not, it would be good if someone can clarify on it.

Comment: Did you read Semver? 0.X is a clear indication it is not "stable" per se. It doesn't mean it can't be used on production though, as long as the product owner follows the rules of the semantic versioning. However one must be aware that there can be breaking changes between `0.X` and `0.X+1`. If you are after stable dependencies you should require `0.X.*` then.